# Read XML using SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml

I am using following code to read the specified XML

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<feed version=\"0.3\" xmlns=\"http://purl.org/atom/ns#\">
    <title>Gmail - Inbox for xxxx@gmail.com</title>
    <tagline>New messages in your Gmail Inbox</tagline>
    <fullcount>1</fullcount>
    <link rel=\"alternate\" href=\"https://mail.google.com/mail\" type=\"text/html\" />
    <modified>2016-02-07T12:11:21Z</modified>
    <entry>
        <title>Access for less secure apps has been turned on</title>
        <summary>Access for less secure apps has been turned on Hi Buddy, You recently changed your security settings so</summary>
        <link rel=\"alternate\" href=\"https://mail.google.com/mail?account_id=agl.testauto@gmail.com&amp;message_id=152bb8ccd28d824b&amp;view=conv&amp;extsrc=atom\" type=\"text/html\" />
        <modified>2016-02-07T11:45:12Z</modified>
        <issued>2016-02-07T11:45:12Z</issued>
        <id>tag:gmail.google.com,2004:1525516088640373323</id>
        <author>
            <name>Google</name>
            <email>no-reply@accounts.google.com</email>
        </author>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Below code is being used and problem is I am not getting values for `title` element with last line of code.

```
response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(objclient.DownloadData("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"));
response = response.Replace("<feed version*\"0.3\" xmlns=\"http://purl.org/atom/01#\">", "<feed>");

xdoc.LoadXml(response);

var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("feed", "http://purl.org/atom/ns#");
node = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//feed:fullcount", nsmgr);


Variables.emailcount = Convert.ToInt16(node.InnerText);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(Variables.emailcount);

tagline = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//feed:tagline", nsmgr).InnerText;

node2 = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//feed:entry", nsmgr);

message_subject = node2.SelectSingleNode("//feed/entry/title", nsmg).InnerText;    ---- >>>  Issue Line
```

Just wondering where could be the issue.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, why you removed namespace then re introduce it? Anyway, try //feed:entry/title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

> message_subject = node2.SelectSingleNode("//feed:entry/feed:title",
>   nsmgr).InnerText;

note: you have used "feed" as the name of the namespace, so the title should also be qualified

Answer (score 2):

Make your life easier by using `SyndicationFeed` defined into `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace from `System.ServiceModel` assembly.

```
SyndicationFeed syndicationFeed = null;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"))
{
    syndicationFeed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
}

if(syndicationFeed != null)
{
    foreach (SyndicationItem item in syndicationFeed.Items)
    {
        // Do everything you want here by checking properties you need from SyndicationItem item variable.
    }
}
```

To know what are properties that `SyndicationItem` offer check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem_properties(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const int NUMBER_OF_XML = 3;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                    "<feed version=\"0.3\" xmlns=\"http://purl.org/atom/ns#\">" +
                        "<title>Gmail - Inbox for xxxx@gmail.com</title>" +
                        "<tagline>New messages in your Gmail Inbox</tagline>" +
                        "<fullcount>1</fullcount>" +
                        "<link rel=\"alternate\" href=\"https://mail.google.com/mail\" type=\"text/html\" />" +
                        "<modified>2016-02-07T12:11:21Z</modified>" +
                        "<entry>" +
                            "<title>Access for less secure apps has been turned on</title>" +
                            "<summary>Access for less secure apps has been turned on Hi Buddy, You recently changed your security settings so</summary>" +
                            "<link rel=\"alternate\" href=\"https://mail.google.com/mail?account_id=agl.testauto@gmail.com&amp;message_id=152bb8ccd28d824b&amp;view=conv&amp;extsrc=atom\" type=\"text/html\" />" +
                            "<modified>2016-02-07T11:45:12Z</modified>" +
                            "<issued>2016-02-07T11:45:12Z</issued>" +
                            "<id>tag:gmail.google.com,2004:1525516088640373323</id>" +
                            "<author>" +
                                "<name>Google</name>" +
                                "<email>no-reply@accounts.google.com</email>" +
                            "</author>" +
                        "</entry>" +
                    "</feed>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement firstNode = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = firstNode.Name.Namespace;
            var results = doc.Elements(ns + "feed").Select(x => new {
                    tagline = (string)x.Element(ns + "tagline"),
                    message_subject = (string)x.Element(ns + "entry").Element(ns + "title")
                }).FirstOrDefault();


        }
    }
}
```